# forward html header parameter to jsf back bean

Tags: java, jsf, http-headers

I have two servers
one is just for authentication and forward request with userId in header parameter
other server runs application on JSF (1.2). 
how can I retrieve parameter from request and put in backing beans.

Comment: You're mixing the terms "request header" and "request parameter" and your question is therefore ambiguous and confusing. Please edit and explicitly specify "request header" OR "request parameter". The request header is whatever goes in HTTP header field (and is not visible in URL). The request parameter is whatever goes in request URL after `?` part. Also, a "forward" from Server X to Server Y is impossible. You probably mean "redirect" here. Considering that, it's impossible to let the browser add another request header when sending a redirect. So, what do you *really* have and need to do?

Comment: Elaborating in detail and along code examples how exactly you're calling the other server would be more than helpful in understanding what you *really* have and are doing. Are you using for example `URLConnection` or some specific API?

Comment: I read your article Communication in JSF, It is very interesting. 
My problem starts with:
I am a spring struts user and new to JSF. All I am told by admins is that the userId will be in http header of the request which will land on my starting page of application. I need to pull the information from the request and put in the backing bean which I will use through out the session. I am trying to understand before I start the coding.

Comment: Ah right, you aren't forwarding by yourself at all, you just need to check the incoming request header. In that case, maple's answer is perfectly fine. You just have to determine what request header name is been used so that you can use it in map's `get()` method.

Comment: @BalusC I think what the OP means is that his JSF application server is sitting behind a proxy server that automatically inputs information into the request headers.

Comment: @maple: Yes, I understood that afterwards. The initial question was really confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similar for a single sign on authentication module.  A proxy server inserts a username into the HTTP request header.  This can be retrieved from the `FacesContext` like so:

```
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = context.getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap();
String userName = requestHeaders.get(requestHeaderName);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this thing sounds very encouraging but I have a question.
how does jsf forwards this to backing bean ? or just doing this in backing bean will automatically pick it up ?

Comment: As long as the other server always adds this request header and forwards to the JSF application then adding this code in the backing bean should automatically pick it up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I am new to JSF. isnt Context open to all sessions ?
I will try it and send it for deployment and testing and see how it works. As soon as I get any positive results I will update.

Comment: Just get the current instance statically. It's always there as long as you're in JSF context (i.e. you're inside some method which is executed during a JSF request).